# How to change destination folder Location at server side use java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

### My java  Code is Here :-

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Data");  // folder
            profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "video/mp4");  // MIME type
            profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // disable the built-in viewer
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);

            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);

            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
            driver.get("http://www.sample-videos.com/");
```

i am trying to download videos but i want to change destination location

profile.setPreference("C:\Data");  //

instead of this path i need to replace server path reason for insufficent space of my local system

Comment: And what is the problem with "browser.download.dir" ?

Comment: What do you mean by server path? Do you want to download or upload ?

Comment: i am downloading videos its working fine but i want change directory  instead of "C:\Data" of server location

Comment: Sorry, i give up. I do not understand you. Explain what is working and what is not working with examples.

Comment: my problem is i cant able download to server

Comment: We do not know your environment. Ask your server administrator for access to the path your want to write to.

Answer (score 0):

Just add preference like this:

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","PATH_TO_YOUR_DESIRED_LOCATION");
```

I think, this may help you.

Comment: i already given "browser.download.dir",    PATH_TO_YOUR_DESIRED_LOCATION is folder inside server so when try give server path its downloading at defualt download folder in local system